# How to merge collection in EF query

Tags: entity-framework, collections, lambda, merge

An order have many order-detail
I want to query all order-detail of some order and combine them into only one IEnumerable
How can I do that? The code below return `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<OrderDetail>>`

```
db.Order.Where(o=>o.OrderDate > date1).select(o=>o.OrderDetail)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Projects each element of a sequence to an `IEnumerable<T>` and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

```
db.Order.Where(o => o.OrderDate > date1).SelectMany(o => o.OrderDetail);
```